# How to get pffile from pfobject using Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to get a file from my PFUser object with by simply:

```
PFFile *userImageFile = gaUser[@"@userImage"];
```

This returns nil.

This is what it looks like in my method:

```
- (void)getRemoteImageAndSaveLocalWithObjectId:(NSString *)objectId andType:(NSString *)type{
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"user"]) {
        PFQuery *query = [GAUser query];
        // I tried the include key but I get an error.
        //[query includeKey:@"userImage"];
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            GAUser *gaUser = (GAUser *)object;
            // this is nil
            PFFile *userImageFile = gaUser[@"userImage"];

            if (userImageFile){
            [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"in get data");
                if (!error) {

                    NSLog(@"remote image name: %@",data.debugDescription);

                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


                }else{

                    NSLog(@"there was an error");
                }
            }];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"user image file is nil");
            }

        }];
    }
```

This prints: `user image file is nil`

My parse console looks like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the string you're indexing with `@userImage` and not just `userImage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since in Parse your column is named `userImage`, you should be accessing it with:

```
PFFile *userImageFile = gaUser[@"userImage"];
```

instead of

```
PFFile *userImageFile = gaUser[@"@userImage"];
```